# What does it mean when Installshield's prerequisite fails with error "Prerequisites returning 2"?

Tags: installshield

I am using revenera InstallShield 2021. I've added a new pre-requisite ReportViewer 2015 which needs to be installed first. The installer installs the pre-requisite fine but fails with "Prerequisites returning 2". When I install the prerequisite as a standalone it installs fine without any issues. I tried to find what it means by "prerequisites returning 2" but didn't get any help even from the InstallShield's documentation.

Below is the error detail. Please let me know what is wrong with it.

[image]

Note: This only happens when a previous version of Report Viewer is installs and Report Viewer 2015 tries to update it.